# How to insert into a database as fast as possible (multi-threaded program)?

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

I have a php script on my server which connects to the MySQL database and inserts into on duplicate key (insert or update).

My Java programm which calls the php script on the server runs multiple threads for the different categories from the website I download the content from.

My programm structure looks like this:

- Grab links to download content from
- Start (for example) 10 threads (one for each categorie)

  - In each thread insert a row n times (call the php script)

If I execute this, I get deadlocks on the database.

So my question is, how to setup this programm to insert the downloaded content from the website as fast as possible without running into deadlocks?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider creating a ConnectionPool and get connection from this pool for your database and try to do batch inserts for high volume of data.

Comment: So it is faster to insert into 10,000 rows at once then insert 1 row 10,000 times?

Comment: YES , it is faster to insert 100-200 rows batches than one by one inserts.You can use java prepared statement with approriate batch size and committ. we had application with 10 million inserts everyday, we were using similar techniques.